# Wordpress - query_posts() and post__in doesn't work

Tags: wordpress

I've a problem with my `query_posts()` call.

Here is my code:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_id FROM " . $wpdb->postmeta . " WHERE meta_key = 'mashsb_shares' ORDER BY CAST(meta_value AS SIGNED) DESC LIMIT 0, 20");

$top_ideas = array();

foreach($results as $result) {
    foreach($result as $key => $value) {
        array_push($top_ideas, $value);
    }
}
print_r($top_ideas);

query_posts( array( 'post__in' => $top_ideas, 'orderby' => 'post__in' ) );
```

My problem is that posts doesn't appear in the order of my `post__in` array (`$top_ideas`).

[Here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0bk0.png)

My `print_r()` shows the right array, so my `$results`'s query works good. The problem is in my `query_posts()` call, but I can't find what problem is...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `'orderby' => 'ID' `

Comment: According to this [doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), _"'post__in' - Preserve post ID order given in the post__in array."_ and this is what I need, not order by ID.

Comment: I am having this EXACT same issue on a site where the post__in order was working in the past. I did find this in the Wordpress bug tracker, but not sure if it's related or not. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/38034#trac-add-comment

Did you ever resolve this issue?